# Preserving the CDATA format with a SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser, cdata

I'm trying to parse an XML file and insert some attributes in my database. I'm developing in JAVA and using SAX to parse the XML file.

My problem is that when I read an attribute in CDATA format I only get what the CDATA contains. Perhaps I wan't to keep the CDATA format?

For example with the XML below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Bank>
        <Account type="saving">
            <Id>1001</Id>
            <Name><![CDATA[<Jack> <Robinson>]]></Name>
            <Amt>10000</Amt>
        </Account>
        <Account type="current">
            <Id>1002</Id>
            <Name>Sony Corporation</Name>
            <Amt>1000000</Amt>
        </Account>
    </Bank>
```

I would like to get the `Name` and have it like this `<![CDATA[<Jack> <Robinson>]]>` and not only `<Jack> <Robinson>` which is what I am getting.

Can anyone help me with this issue please.

PS : Sorry for my English, I'm french.

Best regards,

Comment: Why do you care about getting the markup used to express the data instead of the data itself?

Comment: You don't need CDATA sections unless you generate XML by using `print`. Don't do that, use a proper XML library instead.

Answer (score -1):

Like @Quentin asked, I am curious why do you care about markup.

Did you consider appending `<![CDATA[` and `]]` using `StringBuffer` manually in your output.

Comment: I need the markup and the data because we think that at lease once I'll need to create an XML file with those data from my dataBase. 

And if I have to add the markup manually I should only add it on the concerned attributs ( only thoses markedup already )*